# Uglifyjs 3.3.27 doesnt like my regular expression

Tags: uglifyjs

I'm running this code as expected on the browser, however, in my build process, it fails when it comes to 'uglify' the code.

```
var match = data.url.match(/(?:[^\/][\d\w.]+)$(?<=(?:.pdf))/im);
                                       ^
ERROR: Invalid regular expression: /(?:[^\/][\d\w.]+)$(?<=(?:.pdf))/: Invalid group
```

This is a regex checker online : https://regex101.com/r/VWwTsx/2/ (unique url to my regex)